# Android: how to put data into a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog

How to infuse data into my dialog using the builder?

I want to use an adapter on R.layout.history (which is set as view in the 3rd line of the class). But it appears I can't do it inside the FireMissiles class.

How can I use an adapter on that view to populate it with data?

```
public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.history, null));


        builder.setTitle("History");

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I use an adapter on that view to populate it with data?

You can use the AlertDialog.Builder class and call `setItems()` or `setMultipleChoiceItems()` to pass an Array of data and have the Dialog populate a ListView for you.

Or you can create your own ListView (or Spinner, etc) like normal and pass this layout to any Dialog's `setContentView()` method. (You don't necessarily need to use the AlertDialog.Builder.)

Answer (score 0):

I hope layout.history is of type ListView or AdapterView. 
This is how you can do it:

ListView lview = (ListView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.history, null);

lview.setAdapter(adapter); // Pass adapter as constructor of FireMissilesDialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line:

```
builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.history, null));
```

which creates and sets the view at the same time, split them like this:

```
View v = infalter.inflate(R.layout.history, null));
// ... Some code here that sets up the view with your data.
builder.setView(v);
```

You'll want v to be of the same type as the root layout for R.layout.history.  You can get it's children with `v.findViewById()` just as you would any dynamically created/referenced ViewGroup.